# Quisiera que en lugar de que mi codigo imprima en consola, imprima los datos en una ventana de windows

Tags: c, winapi

Buenas noches quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme, tengo un ejercicio que hice para el leguaje c.
Estoy usando winapi para crear messages box en algunos mensajes que tiene que mandar mi programa según algunos eventos. Ahora Necesito que los prints que saldrán en consola salgan en una ventana de windows en lugar de la consola...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MAX 20


struct param {
  int num_estudiante;
  int num_grupo;
};

struct param buffer[MAX];

sem_t huecos,elementos,mutex;

int pos_productor= 0;
int num_estudiantes, cantidad_grupos, plazas_por_grupo;
int *grupo_de_alumno;
int *plazas_libres;

void init_datos() {

int i;

grupo_de_alumno= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num_estudiantes);
for (i= 0; i< num_estudiantes; i++)
    grupo_de_alumno[i]= -1;
plazas_libres= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cantidad_grupos);
for (i= 0; i< cantidad_grupos; i++)
    plazas_libres[i]= plazas_por_grupo;
}

int *decide_preferencias (void){

    int *peticiones;
    int i, pos1, pos2, aux;

    peticiones= (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*cantidad_grupos);
    for(i=0; i< cantidad_grupos; i++)
        peticiones[i]= i;
    for (i=0; i< cantidad_grupos; i++){
        pos1= rand() %cantidad_grupos;
        pos2= rand() %cantidad_grupos;
        aux= peticiones[pos1];
        peticiones[pos1]= peticiones[pos2];
        peticiones[pos2]= aux;
    }
    return peticiones;
}

    int grupo_asignado(int num_estudiante){
        return (grupo_de_alumno[num_estudiante]);
    }

    int hay_plazas_libres (int num_grupo) {
        return (plazas_libres[num_grupo]>0);
    }

void asignar_grupo (int estudiante, int grupo){

    if (grupo_de_alumno[estudiante]==-1){
        grupo_de_alumno[estudiante]= grupo;
        plazas_libres[grupo]--;
    }

    else {
        printf("Error inesperado\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}

void *productor(void *p){

    int num_estudiante= *(int *)p;
    int i;
    int *peticiones;
    struct param dato;

    peticiones= decide_preferencias();
    for (i=0; i< cantidad_grupos; i++) {
        dato.num_estudiante= num_estudiante;
        dato.num_grupo= peticiones[i];
        printf("El estudiante %d pide el grupo %d\n", num_estudiante, peticiones[i]);
        sem_wait(&huecos);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        buffer[pos_productor]= dato;
        pos_productor= (pos_productor+1) %MAX;
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&elementos);
        if (grupo_asignado(num_estudiante) !=-1)
            pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Exactamente en esta parte de consumidar quisiera que esos datos de los prints salga en una ventana de windows y no en la consola

```
void *consumidor (void *p) {

    int pos_consumidor= 0;
    int asignados= 0;
    struct param dato;

    while (asignados< num_estudiantes) {
        sem_wait(&elementos);
        dato= buffer[pos_consumidor];
        pos_consumidor= (pos_consumidor+1) %MAX;
        sem_post(&huecos);

        if (hay_plazas_libres(dato.num_grupo)) {
            if (grupo_asignado(dato.num_estudiante)!=-1)
                printf("Peticion rechazada. Estudiante %d, grupo %d. El estudiante ya tiene grupo asignado\n", dato.num_estudiante,dato.num_grupo);
            else{
             asignar_grupo(dato.num_estudiante, dato.num_grupo);
             printf("Al estudiante %d se le asigna el grupo %d\n",dato.num_estudiante, dato.num_grupo);
             asignados++;
            }
        }else
             printf("Peticion rechazada. Estudiante %d, grupo %d. Grupo lleno\n", dato.num_estudiante,dato.num_grupo);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Por ejemplo aqui en el main logre que salga esas advertencias con el MessageBox

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t *estudiantes, gestor;
    int i, *datos;

    if (argc!= 4) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error, debe proporcionar tres paramtetros: Num. estudiates, Num. de grupos y Tamano de grupo", "Error de parametros", MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING);

        exit(1);
    }

    num_estudiantes= atoi(argv[1]);
    cantidad_grupos= atoi(argv[2]);
    plazas_por_grupo= atoi(argv[3]);

    if (num_estudiantes> cantidad_grupos*plazas_por_grupo) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error, No hay plazas para todos los estudiantes", "Error de parametros", MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING);
        exit(1);
    }
    init_datos();
    datos= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*num_estudiantes);
    estudiantes= (pthread_t*)
    malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*num_estudiantes);

    sem_init(&huecos, 0, MAX);
    sem_init(&elementos, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

    pthread_create (&gestor, NULL, consumidor, NULL);
    for (i= 0; i< num_estudiantes; i++) {
        datos[i]= i;
        pthread_create (&estudiantes[i], NULL, productor, &datos[i]);
    }

    pthread_join(gestor, NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Probaste cambiando los `printf` por `MessageBox`?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @julio Si ya probé y me lanza error a la hora de compilar, aparte que si funcionara de esa forma por cada linea se me abriría una ventana o no